# Cython ImportError in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, cython

I'm trying to use Cython in a Jupyter Notebook but keep encountering an error along the lines of `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__cython_magic_82a8b66e5f67c5dfa3ef71998eb9b501)` (full error message at the end).

Is there something I can configure in Jupyter, Cython, Python, or elsewhere that might get Cython working for me here?

My notebook looks like:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

```
%%cython
cpdef int a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a += i
print(a)
```

I'm running Python 3.6.8, Cython 0.29.21 and Jupyter Notebook 5.7.8 from an Anaconda install, on a Windows 10 (64 bit) computer.

To install Cython I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59167121/12849306): 1. install Cython to my environment with `conda intall cython`; 2. install Visual Studio Build Tools with the specified components; 3. copy rc.exe and rcdll.dll to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`. I've previously had Cython working on another computer following the same instructions.

Changing the code below the `%%cython` magic changes the string at the end of the error message (e.g. changing to `a=1` produces `(PyInit__cython_magic_0be2696ff7de958048f532034feee7fd)`), but nothing else.

I've tried searching for other questions with the same error, but most results are for `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723206/cython-compilation-error-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function) (and these other questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719086/cpython-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713957/cythonize-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function)) has a similar `module export function` issue as me, but isn't using Jupyter, so I'm not sure how to translate the solution to my situation (if it even is the same issue).

Full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5e6525b05fe4> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('cython', '', 'cpdef int a = 0\nfor i in range(10):\n    a += i\nprint(a)\n')

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

<decorator-gen-129> in cython(self, line, cell)

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py in cython(self, line, cell)
    349             return None
    350 
--> 351         module = imp.load_dynamic(module_name, module_path)
    352         self._import_all(module)
    353 

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 
    345 else:

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load(spec)

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in module_from_spec(spec)

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in create_module(self, spec)

C:\Anaconda\envs\stable\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__cython_magic_82a8b66e5f67c5dfa3ef71998eb9b501)
```